# unix shell script to check result of sql query

Tags: shell

I have the code like this

> v_use_xref_result=`sqlplus -s $UP <
>
> ```
>    Select Code_Desc 
>    From Code_Detail 
>    Where Code='UXLOC' 
>    and CODE_TYPE='UXRF'
>        EOF`
>  if [ "$v_use_xref_result" == "Y" ];  then
>   echo "s"  else
>   echo "n"
>     fi
> ```

when I query the same in sql developer I am getting the result as Y for this query `Select Code_Desc From Code_Detail Where Code='UXLOC' and CODE_TYPE='UXRF'` the datatype of Code_Desc is varchar
but I am unable to check in if condition. i am getting "n" as result for this script. 
can anyone help me how to check it in if condition.

Answer (score 1):

As written, the heredoc syntax in your script doesn't seem to be correct.  Try saying:

```
v_use_xref_result=$(sqlplus -s $UP <<EOF
   Select Code_Desc 
   From Code_Detail 
   Where Code='UXLOC' 
   and CODE_TYPE='UXRF'
EOF
)
```